# error displaying images - code from PHP & MySQL Novice to Ninja

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am new to PHP and MySQL and in 2 chapters of Kevin Yank's book - PHP & MySQL Novice to Ninja there are mistakes in the code. The only one I haven't figured out lies in chapter 12, and having tried suggestions from multiple posts on this and other fora, nothing works. Thanks to in advance for your help

Problem: Blob gives problem to load:

> The image "http://localhost/chapter12/filestore5/index.php?action=view&id=5" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

All other functions: upload, description, delete works perfectly.

index.php file

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'upload') {

    // Bail out if the file isn't really an upload

    if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $error = 'There was no file uploaded!';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

        exit();
    }

    $uploadfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $uploadtype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $uploaddesc = $_POST['desc'];
    $uploaddata = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
    include 'db.inc.php';

    try {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO filestore SET
    filename = :filename,
    mimetype = :mimetype,
    description = :description,
    filedata = :filedata';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':filename', $uploadname);
        $s->bindValue(':mimetype', $uploadtype);
        $s->bindValue(':description', $uploaddesc);
        $s->bindValue(':filedata', $uploaddata);
        $s->execute();
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Database error storing file!';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action'] == 'view' or $_GET['action'] == 'download') and isset($_GET['id'])) {
    include 'db.inc.php';

    try {
        $sql = 'SELECT filename, mimetype, filedata
    FROM filestore
    WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id']);
        $s->execute();
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Database error fetching requested file.';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

        exit();
    }

    $file = $s->fetch();
    if (!$file) {
        $error = 'File with specified ID not found in the database!';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

        exit();
    }

    $filename = $file['filename'];
    $mimetype = $file['mimetype'];
    $filedata = $file['filedata'];
    $disposition = 'inline';
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'download') {
        $mimetype = 'application/octet-stream';
        $disposition = 'attachment';
    }

    // Content-type must come before Content-disposition

    header('Content-length: ' . strlen($filedata));
    header("Content-type: $mimetype");
    header("Content-disposition: $disposition; filename=$filename");
    echo $filedata;
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'delete' and isset($_POST['id'])) {
    include 'db.inc.php';

    try {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM filestore
    WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s->execute();
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Database error deleting requested file.';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}

include 'db.inc.php';

try {
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, filename, mimetype, description
    FROM filestore');
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Database error fetching stored files.';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';

    exit();
}

$files = array();

foreach($result as $row) {
    $files[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'filename' => $row['filename'],
        'mimetype' => $row['mimetype'],
        'description' => $row['description']
    );
}

include 'files.html.php';

?>
```

HTML file

```
<?php 
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP/MySQL File Repository</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PHP/MySQL File Repository</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="upload">Upload File:
                <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="desc">File Description:
                <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc"
                    maxlength="255"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php if (count($files) > 0): ?>
        <p>The following files are stored in the database:</p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Filename</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($files as $f): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>
                            "><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php htmlout($f['mimetype']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php htmlout($f['description']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="" method="get">
                            <div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="action"
                                    value="download"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id"
                                    value="<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id"
                                    value="<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indenting your code makes it a lot easier to read.  Code you can read is a lot easier to debug.

Comment: thanks, i was indenting until i got so fed up with trying to fix i copied and pasted straight from the book to make the error wasn't coming from my side. This might be easier: https://github.com/spbooks/PHPMYSQL5/tree/master/chapter12/filestore 
the code is better indented there if you want to have an alternate view

Comment: Where is the code that displays ( or tries to display ) the image?

Comment: The data you are storing in the database, specifically the image data, eithe rneeds to be `base64_encode`d before storing in the database or immediately prior to attempting to generate an image - that is assuming you are trying to output an image like `<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, #####' /> ~ the `#####` should be the base64encoded string rather than RAW binary data

Comment: Forgive my million deletes of comments - hard to get accustomed to a comment automatically being posted after hitting Enter - I am accustomed to Slack. N e hoos, my code for displaying the image is:
`<?php foreach($files as $f): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>
                            "><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?></a>
                    </td>` 
I think the base64 may be the answer - on a Youtube tutorial I successfully was able to display a blob. (comment continued below)

Comment: The code in the Youtube tutorial in which I successfully displayed a blob was `<embed src='data:" $row[' mime' ." ;base64,".base64_encode($row[' data' ])"'>` . Although I tried to superimpose that on my code above, I suppose I was unsuccessful because I don't have the knowledge. Can you please advise, the best place put the base64_encode clause in `<a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?> "><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got back to fixing the code and found a workable solution here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/problem-using-php-to-pull-binary-files-from-a-blob-field-in-mysql/6431/16 
I added in "while (@ob_end_clean());" after the magicquotes in index.php and all works well.
According to what this person found in another forum, if server has output buffering on, then it won't send the image data correctly.